# Terraform azapi provider ChainedTokenCredential authentication failed

Tags: authentication, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azapi

I'm trying to use terraform's azapi to deploy a quota alarm and I'm running into an error with oath "Identity not found"

I have my provider set up with:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.43.0"
    }
    azapi = {
      source = "azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  tenant_id                  = "<Tenant ID>"
  subscription_id            = <Subscription ID 1>
  skip_provider_registration = true
  use_oidc                   = true
  features {}
}
provider "azapi" {
  alias           = "alias1"
  tenant_id       = "<Tenant ID>"
  subscription_id = <Subscription ID 2>
  use_oidc        = true
}
```

I am using GitHub actions and we login to Azure via OIDC.
azurerm is working fine but azapi is failing with:

```
Error: checking for presence of existing Resource: (ResourceId "/subscriptions/<Subscription ID 2>/resourceGroups/quota-alarms/providers/Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules/total_regional_vcpu_quota_alarm" / Api Version "2023-03-15-preview"): ChainedTokenCredential authentication failed
GET http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE 400 Bad Request
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Identity not found"
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any thoughts on why authentication is working for azurerm but not azapi?

Comment: The error message indicates that the identity is not found, and this could be due to various reasons.
Ensure that the managed identity for the resource has been properly configured and has the necessary permissions,Service Principal Permissions and orrect Subscription and Tenant.

Comment: Thank you but that is fairly vague.  I'm wondering if the identity that's missing is for the provider or the scheduled query.  I'm trying to understand at what point in the terraform process this is failing.  I should add that I have successfully deployed this terraform in a separate subscription from my dev machine but I suspect that was using the azure cli for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this myself.

The problem was that I was specifying an alias name in the provider block but not in the azapi_resource block.  I think it was trying to fall back to a generic azapi provider which works on my dev machine because I have AZ CLI setup.

I specified a provider alias in the resource block and it worked:

```
resource "azapi_resource" "compute_quota_alarms" {
  provider = azapi.alias1
```